# Number of list elements less than a given integer

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, function-construction

I'm trying to make a function whose input is a list, and that outputs a list for which the nth element is the number of elements in the input less than n. 
So far, I have

```
l2 = Table[Length[Select[l1, # < n &]], {n, 1, M}]
```

Where l2 is the output list, l1 is the input list, and M is the desired length of l2.
This gives the correct output, but is there a faster way to do this, as this function can get rather slow for larger lists.

An example of the function:

{2,2,3,3,7} —$>$ {0,0,2,4,4}.

Comment: Is your input list always sorted?

Comment: Yes it is always sorted

Answer (score 6):

The [`BoolEval`](https://github.com/szhorvat/BoolEval) package can be used here to get a good combination of performance and clean syntax:

```
<< BoolEval`
Table[BoolCount[list < n], {n, 5}]
```

> `{0, 0, 2, 4, 4}`

Answer (score 6):

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 100}, 100000];
Accumulate[BinCounts[list, {0, Ceiling[Max[list]], 1}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = {2, 2, 3, 3, 7};
M = 4;
l2  = Table[Length[Select[l1, # < n &]], {n, 1, M}]
```

> {0, 0, 2, 4}

#### [UnitStep](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) + Total

```
Total[1 - UnitStep[l1 - #] & /@ Range[M], {2}]
(* or Total[1 - UnitStep[l1 - #]] & /@ Range[M] *)
```

> {0, 0, 2, 4}

#### [Clip](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html) + [Unitize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unitize.html) + Total

```
Total[1 - Unitize@Clip[l1, {#, ∞}, {0, 1}] & /@ Range[ M], {2}]
(* or Total[1 - Unitize @ Clip[l1, {#, ∞}, {0, 1}]] & /@ Range[M] *)
```

> {0, 0, 2, 4}